# Can i map other folder to Launchpad

Tags: applications, launchpad

I am using OSX 10.8. 
Is it possible to map an extra Application folder to launchpad so that launchpad will pick .app from that folder too ?

I have osx install disk names OSX and i install apps in 'Applications' folder. Now i have added one more disk named "Macintosh" i have installed some programmes in that disk too. I want to get the apps in Macintosh>Applications in Launchpad.

There should be a way right ?

Does that makes sense ?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're asking ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler okay. i have osx install disk names `OSX` and i install apps in 'Applications' folder. Now i have added one more disk named "Macintosh" i have installed some programmes in that disk too. I want to get the apps in Macintosh>Applications in Launchpad. Does that makes sense ?

Comment: I think that won't be so easy. Launchpad does not only require the apps to be in `Applications`, but it also looks for the libraries under `Library`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to "symlink" the files on your other partition to your Applications-Folder.

**For example:**

```
ln -s /Volumes/Macintosh2/Applications2/App.app /Applications/
```

Launchpad follow the symlink and show the Apps.

Comment: Okay i will try this and let you know the result? do i need to symlink all apps ?

Comment: You can try to symlink your App-Folder on the other hard drive/partition

Comment: For all apps at once just use ln -s /Volumes/Macintosh2/Applications2/*.app /Applications/